# Reporting Services and .Net sp 2.0 

Tags: 2007

I have an issue when installing the .net 2.0 sp2. Reporting services stops working. It this an known issue?? Any of you have had this error as well??

Comment: Please provide some more details, such as error messages from event logs or ULS logs (provided you're running in SharePoint Integrated Mode).

Comment: I get this error in the Mosslogs - AppDomainUnloadListener.RegisterSelf() entered lock(this=15368010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed by adding this registry entry.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > System > CurrentControlSet>Control > Lsa 
Add an entry with DWORD value “DisableLoopBackCheck”, set the value to 1.